# Azure CloudBlobDirectory subdirectory

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We have an old app that was developed by an offshore outsourced development company and it is still using Azure Storage client 1.7.

I'm therefore updating it before this version stops working.

There is a unit test that I can't pass.

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void CloudBlobDirectoryTest()
    {
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = _cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient(); 
        string filePath = "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/store1/BCAUK_Reports.sql"; 
        string expected = "store1"; 
        CloudBlobDirectory actual = AzureUtil.CloudBlobDirectory(cloudBlobClient, filePath);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.Container.Name);
    }
```

The method used to look like this:

```
    public static CloudBlobDirectory CloudBlobDirectory(CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient, string filePath)
    {
        CloudBlobDirectory cloudBlobDirectory = cloudBlobClient.GetBlobDirectoryReference(filePath);
        return cloudBlobDirectory;
    }
```

I have refactored this to fit with the new storage API as:

```
    public static CloudBlobDirectory CloudBlobDirectory(CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient, string filePath)
    {
        Uri path = new Uri(filePath);
        string relativePath = "/store1/";

        CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(path.Segments[1]);
        CloudBlobDirectory cloudBlobDirectory = container.GetDirectoryReference(relativePath);

        return cloudBlobDirectory;
    }
```

I can't workout what the value of `relativePath` should be and how I would get this value in a reproducible way.

Answer (score 3):

This is a sort of odd snippet of code. The way directory is being used doesn't really make sense to me since store1 is a container and BCAUK_Reports.sql is a blob -- ie there aren't any directories. Furthermore, the hardcoding of the emulator string seems really odd since this means this test doesn't test anything relative to the live service you'll presumably be using. I'd guess these oddities is why this is not porting well. Could you maybe explain what you intend this to be testing?

That being said, if I guess what you're trying to do it's get the parent directory and container of a blob. If you simply do something like CloudBlockBlob(filepath, client.Credentials) and then do either blob.Container for the blob's container reference or blob.Parent for the blob's parent directory that might work.

Comment: Agreed that it looks odd, unfortunately there is very little documentation about what it is trying to achieve. Looks like this is going to be more of re-write than I'd hoped.

Comment: @Fishcake Is there anything I can add to my answer to help you out or is this what you need to know to help with the above?